# Identify Cell after Tap Location in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, long-press

I have attached a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a Collection View with the aim of the user hold finger on a cell in the table and being asked if they want to remove it.

The problem I have is that I can not get the indexPath like I would with a table cell (using indexPathForRowAtPoint), is there an equivalent?

If not I have thought about adding the gesture to each cell, but then how do I identify the which gesture (I can not see a "tag" for a gesture), e.g. can I send indexPath.item in the selector? Or some other method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You got the same thing on the `UICollectionView`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> indexPathForItemAtPoint: Returns the index path of the item at the
>   specified point in the collection view.
>
> - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForItemAtPoint:(CGPoint)point Parameters point A point in the collection view’s coordinate system. Return Value
>     The index path of the item at the specified point or nil if no item
>     was found at the specified point.
>
> Discussion This method relies on the layout information provided by
>   the associated layout object to determine which item contains the
>   point.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 6.0 and later. Declared In
>   UICollectionView.h

Comment: I tried ForItem as well and it was telling me that there was No Visible Interface for it and on closer inspection I found I was trying to do it on a UIView with near same name as the UIColectionView. I am an idiot for not noticing and for not naming better...  Thanks for heads up on that.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the CGPoint that you get sometimes is coming in the UIViewController reference system and works as long as there is no scrolling involved. When scrolling is involved you need to translate the point to the real point in the scrollable view by adding the offset of the scroll.

In this example the CGPoint is coming from a 3DTouch in the whole UIViewController that contains a UICollectionView inside

```
public func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?{
    let offsetPoint = self.musicCollectionVw.contentOffset
    let realLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x + offsetPoint.x, y: location.y + offsetPoint.y)
    if let indexPath = self.musicCollectionVw.indexPathForItem(at: realLocation){
        NSLog("Section: \(indexPath.section) Row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Exactly the issue I was having (but using Xamarin.iOS) and this has fixed the issue.  But now when I use the 3D Touch, the initial outline of the source cell displays as the preview comes into view.  So to hopefully clarify this more, if I force touch the cell item, the preview begins to come into view but starts expanding at where the original cell is prior to the offset.

Comment: And just an update to my previous comment (which I just worked out after posting it), was if you register the UICollectionView itself in the  RegisterForPreviewingWithDelegate, then the offset isn't required anymore.. thus Xamarin.iOS code is:
               `RegisterForPreviewingWithDelegate(new PhotoPreviewingDelegate(this), this.CollectionView);
`

Comment: I upvoted because your answer led me in the right direction, but what worked for me was to convert the `CGPoint` from my `view` coordinates to my `collectionView` coordinates. `let actualLocation = view.convert(location, to: collectionView)`

Comment: @MichaelPatzer that's the idea. To find the path to the solution. I upvoted you too ;)